# Can someone explain me what the header function actually does?

Tags: php

Can someone explain me what the header function actually does? I looked in the PHP manual but that was not clear to me so I actually didn't understand. Here is the function which I should digest.

```
function ofunc_startusr ($GETID="_usrid_",$FORCE=false)
{
$a = explode(".",$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);
$dom =".".$a[(count($a)-2)].".".$a[(count($a)-1)];

if($GETID!==false && isset($_GET[$GETID]) && $_GET[$GETID])
{
    session_set_cookie_params(0,"/",$dom); 
    session_id($_GET[$GETID]);
    session_name("_usr_"); 
    session_start();
 header("Location: ".($_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]?                                  

     $_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]:"/")); 

    exit;
} 
elseif($FORCE || (isset($_COOKIE["_usr_"]) && $_COOKIE["_usr_"]))
{
    session_set_cookie_params(0,"/",$dom);
    session_name("_usr_"); 
    session_start();

    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: Have you read the manual?

Comment: It arranges for HTTP response headers to be sent. So you might want to read about how HTTP works.

Comment: its used to send a raw HTTP header :)

Comment: This may help: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/http-headers-for-dummies/

Comment: You should ask yourself the question _"What do HTTP headers actually mean/do?"_, then imagine being able to manipulate/set the headers yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using HTTP, the client will make a request and the server will make a response. There are two parts to each of these - the headers and the (optional) body.

For example, when you submit a form, the browser will make a POST request. The headers will include things like the URL the form is being submitted to, and the body will include the data from the form.

When the server makes a response, it will first send the headers and then the body. The headers will include information such as what sort of data the body contains (such as "This is an HTML document" or "This is a PNG image"), what time the resource was last modified (for caching purposes), new cookies to set, and so on. The body will then contain the HTML document / image / etc.

The PHP `header` function lets you specify the headers you want to send back.